# Connecting to TFS Api in Angular, 401 unauthorized

Tags: angular, api, authentication, tfs, authorization

I've encountered a problem with API get request in my first Angular app. I'm trying to get all projects from a server, I've got the correct url(it works in postman, even in my browser), I've also generated a token from my account on TFS, however, I still get a 401 unauthorized in the console when I run the app. Any help would be apprecieated. Do I need to provide Windows authentication? Is it even possible on Angular?

Here's the method I'm trying to run. All imports are there, and the method is called from OnInit.

```
  getProjects(): void {
    const authHeader = new HttpHeaders(); 
    authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + 
    `perfectly valid token here`);
    this.http.get('perfectly valid server url here/_apis/projects?api-
    version=1.0', {headers: authHeader}).subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
  }
```

Comment: Tried encoding it to BASE64 with btoa() but still not working.

Comment: How do you generate the token?

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working using a Basic Authentication.

```
getProjects(): void {
    const authHeader = new HttpHeaders(); 
    authHeader.append('Authorization', 'Basic ' + 
    base64('Username:Password'));
    this.http.get('perfectly valid server url here/_apis/projects?api-
    version=1.0', {headers: authHeader}).subscribe(data => {
      this.results = data['results'];
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try providing Windows authentication,It's available on Angular. And enable CORS within the project.

Then check [Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/rest/basics#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors) example below to add Authorization in your code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://fabrikam.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/projects?api-version=1.0',
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa("" + ":" + myPatToken)
        }
    }).done(function( results ) {
        console.log( results.value[0].id + " " + results.value[0].name );
    });
});
```

You can reference these articles for further troubleshooting:

- [AngularJS & Web API Active Directory Security](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1022870/AngularJS-Web-API-Active-Directory-Security)
- [HOW TO IMPLEMENT WINDOWS AUTHENTICATION IN AN ANGULARJS APPLICATION
  WITH A STAND-ALONE WEB API](https://spikesapps.wordpress.com/2016/09/08/how-to-implement-windows-authentication-in-an-angularjs-application-with-a-stand-alone-web-api/)